# Swap super and ctrl keys in xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap

I'm trying to swap my ctrl and super keys.
I currently have successfully mapped the super keys to ctrl, now I need to map the ctrl keys to super, but I can't find a way to do so.

Current code:

```
! Map both super to ctrl
remove mod4 = Super_R
add control = Super_R
remove mod4 = Super_L
add control = Super_L

! Map both ctrl to super
! ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Swap left ctrl and super:
`remove mod4 = Super_L`
`remove control = Control_L`
`keycode  133 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L`
`keycode  37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L`
`add mod4 = Super_L`
`add control = Control_L`

and alike for the right (`Super_R` keycode is 134 in my case).
Keycodes may differ for you, use `xmodmap -pke` to find them out.